# Multiple attachment file in email using C#

Tags: c#

How to attach the multiple files in an email using c#.

```
        MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
        SmtpClient SmtpServer = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com");

        //get the userID, Pass
        userID= register.userName;
        password = register.pass;


        string aa=txtTo.Text;
        mail.From = new MailAddress(userID);
        mail.To.Add(aa);
        mail.Subject = txtsubject.Text;
        mail.Body = txtComments.Text;

        //Attach file
        mail.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(txtAttachments.Text.ToString()));       
        SmtpServer.Port = 587;
        SmtpServer.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
        SmtpServer.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(userID, password);
        SmtpServer.EnableSsl = true;
        SmtpServer.Send(mail);
        MessageBox.Show("Email sent successfully");
        this.Cursor = Cursors.Default;

        //close the page
        Email email = new Email();
        email.Close();
```

this code is used for attach one file only. How can i attach multiple files in c# 2008.???
        Plz give me the solution.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
...
mail.Body = txtComments.Text;
//Attach file
mail.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(txtAttachments.Text.ToString()));
mail.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(txtAttachments2.Text.ToString()));
mail.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(txtAttachments3.Text.ToString()));
mail.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(txtAttachments4.Text.ToString()));
SmtpServer.Port = 587;
...
```

Comment: @David how could one go about adding a dynamic amount of attachments?

Answer (score 4):

Multiple attachments can be added to the `Message.Attachments` collection

C#:

```
Message.Attachments.Add(new System.Net.Mail.Attachment(strAttPath));
```

VB:

```
Message.Attachments.Add(New Net.Mail.Attachment(strAttPath))
```

Simply call `.Add` multiple times, pointing to each attachment.

Comment: thanks a lot! you help me with this. +1 - I edit your question (excuse me) because your solution were in vb, I've to translate it to c# as the question is remarked. but anyway thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Just add more attachments to the mail.Attachments collection as you did above.

Answer (score 2):

What about releasing the attachment files after the send?

For example, you send a temporary file used to create the attachment content.  This file is used repetitively for this purpose ongoing.  The attachment file will need to be released with a `dispose()` on the attachment.

To accomplish this create the attachment first to give it an object name to use with dispose() later.

```
Attachment attach = new Attachment(txtAttachments.Text.ToString());    
Message.Attachments.Add(attach);
...

attach.dispose();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
protected void SendMail(List<string> attachments)
    {
        UserManagement Users = new UserManagement();
        Users.GetUserInformation();

        SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient(ip_address);
        MailMessage Message = new MailMessage();
        Message.From = new MailAddress(senderaddress);

        Message.To.Add(Users._CurUser_Destination_Email);
        Message.Subject = "Neue Umlagerung - " + cb_auflieger_limburg.SelectedItem.ToString();

        Message.Body = string.Format("Datum: {0}", DateTime.Now) + Environment.NewLine +
                                     "AufliegerNr.: " + cb_auflieger_limburg.SelectedItem.ToString() + Environment.NewLine +
                                     "Benutzer: " + Environment.UserName;

        client.UseDefaultCredentials = true;

        Attachment Attachment = null;

        try
        {
            foreach (string attachment in attachments)
            {
                Attachment = new Attachment(attachment);
                Message.Attachments.Add(Attachment);
            }

            client.Send(Message);
            Attachment.Dispose();
            Message.Dispose();
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }
        finally
        {
            foreach(string attachment in attachments)
            {
                //Dateien nach Versendung löschen
                FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(attachment);
                if (fi.Exists)
                {
                    fi.Delete();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

The parameter **List attachments** gets filled by a class that exports a DataGridView in different formats like .csv and .pdf

The List "atttachments" contains the strings of the folder and filename.

```
//Exporting to CSV.
string FileName = $"YourFileName_{datetime}.csv";
File.WriteAllText(ExportPath + FileName, csv);

AttachmentsToExport.Add(ExportPath + FileName);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
            try
            {
                Attachment Attachment = null;
                foreach (string csv in CsvFilepath)
                {
                    Attachment = new Attachment(csv, new ContentType()
                    {
                        MediaType = "text/csv",
                        Name = FolderName + ".csv"
                    });
                    mailMessage.Attachments.Add(Attachment);
                }
                emailClient.Send(mailMessage);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }
```

Comment: Your answer doesn't provide more information than the existing answers (especially [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53740996/10352740)), I think you should read the [help center for answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/answering), especially [How to answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) and [Reasons leading to answer deletion](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)