# multiple attachment in c# not working

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, email

[In Answer of  this questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1457940/multiple-attachment-file-in-email-using-c-sharp)  there has a way to  multiple attachment in c# . By following this I write a code like this:
Initialization:

```
     Attachment []attach=new Attachment[10];
```

then:for every attach_num

```
    attach[attach_num] = new Attachment(file_path);
```

and then attaching in message:

```
      for (int i = 0; i < attach_num; i++)
         {
            mmsg.Attachments.Add(attach[i]);

         }
```

problem:the message send but with no attachment.Don't show any error. what is the problem? any one can help me?

**please notice It:**

> I could not answer all of you in time,I am sorry for that.I apologies
>   because problem was in my own code. For checking attachment,I have a
>   boolean variable "IfanyAttach",it was initialize by false. when I add
>   attach I turn it to true.But I forget to dot it, so when i check
>   "ifanyAttach" it always give false and never find attachment.  I am
>   sorry that am not check it properly. thanks every body for many many
>   minus. it help me to be serious to my work. thanks everybody.

Comment: How are you initializing `attach_num`?

Comment: Can you post more code?  It's hard to tell what attach_num gets set to and where you are adding the attachments to the message in relation to when the message is created and sent.

Comment: I initializing attach_num as int @JuanManuel

Comment: If you initialize attach_num as int, it is still zero. Can you post more code? It seems that you switched `>` into `<`, which makes me think that this is not a copy of your own code, but hand-typed. Can you do a real copy/paste of a working example (that has your prb)?

Comment: @lazyking: It's poor style IMO to edit your post to make my answer look non-sensical. Now, check your failing code - does it look like your pre-edit code, or your post-edit code?

Comment: I voted to close - as this question was changed without any edit reason behind it, it makes us who try to answer the question all the more confused.

Answer (score 2):

EDIT: Just for the record, this *was* the code in the post when I posted my answer. It's since been silently corrected. It's not clear whether this was *only* a problem in the original post, or whether it was also in the OP's *real* code which wasn't working. It would, of course, explain everything.

---

This is the problem:

```
for (int i = 0; i > attach_num; i++)
```

How many times do you think that loop's going to iterate? :)

(Just one more reason to favour `foreach` loops...)

Comment: foreach are read only Jon.  Just because someone messed up `>` and `<` does not mean you should stop using `for` loops.  I did not downvote you either.

Comment: Now put your bets: is Jon's eyesight failing or did lazy king a very speedy update of his question? score -1, It's a Jon trap!

Comment: @Emo - I don't care if its his eye sight or not - he is human.

Comment: @JonH - of course, but a very fast human, always sneaking away my points, always awake when I am and screening the same tags... I should move to a different timezone

Comment: @JonH (and other Jon) Well, of course, it's always possible that Lazy King changed his post before the famous 5 cooldown minutes passed. Considering that Jon answered 10 mins ago and the post was 11 mins ago, this is a feasible theory, I'd say. This begs the question: did Lazy King try his own code after his own update of switching `>` to  `<`?

Comment: Well, that settles the case (but as it seems, doesn't solve the user's problem) ;)

Comment: @Abel: It was *definitely* like that when I posted - because I cut and paste from the original code into my answer.

Comment: @JonH: Being read-only is irrelevant in this case - because it's only being read in the loop in question, to add to the message's attachments.

Comment: I wasn't ironic, I was serious. I mean: it makes sense. Still, I wonder whether the OP has tried his own edit. Maybe he inadvertently solved his own problem, but wasn't aware of it yet.

Comment: @JonSkeet I understand that but you mentioned just one more reason to favour foreach loops, which could easily be misunderstood.

Comment: @JonH: By "favour" I mean "use where possible, in preference to for loops when both are feasible." Just because they're not *always* appropriate doesn't make the advice to favour/prefer foreach loops any less reasonable.

Comment: for all I say , yes i edit code. that was my typing mistake. but when i edit post in that time i was in that page which is shown after submission . then I read it again and find out my mistake. in that time how i know that one man alrady point if @Abel

Answer (score 0):

It would be much easier and not so error-prone when if you write instaed of

```
for (int i = 0; i < attach_num; i++)
```

the following

```
for (int i = 0; i < attach.Length; i++)
```

The Length property returns the number of items in a given array. What is the reason why you use `attach_num`?

Another approach is that you increment an int in a foreach loop and use the variable to access the array like so

```
int[] int_array = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };

int i = 0;

foreach (int item in int_array)
{
    i++;

    if (i == 2)
    {
        int_array[i] = 7;
    }
}
```

Comment: Make sure that the items in the array list are initialized, otherwise you get an exception. And again: There isn't a difference whether a use a for or foreach loop. It depends on the situation and the appropriate usage.