# add multiple attachements to one e-mail

Tags: c#

i'm sending mails using following code.but i can add only one attachement. i want add more than 30 attachements with one mail. how can i solve this problem. please help me.

```
string fromEmail = "abcd@gmail.com ";
mail_add=recever@gmail.com
MailMessage mailMessage = new MailMessage(fromEmail, mail_add, subject, subject);
System.Net.Mail.Attachment attachement;

attachement = new System.Net.Mail.Attachment("path_with_xl_file");

mailMessage.Attachments.Add(attachement);
mailMessage.Body = body;
MailAddress copy = new MailAddress(fromEmail );
mailMessage.CC.Add(copy);
SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient();
smtpClient.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
smtpClient.Port = 587
smtpClient.EnableSsl = false;
smtpClient.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
smtpClient.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(fromEmail, "mis123");

try
{
    smtpClient.Send(mailMessage);   
}
```

Comment: What is `mail_add=recever@gmail.com`? It should be a `string`, I guess.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multiple attachment file in email using C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1457940/multiple-attachment-file-in-email-using-c-sharp)

Comment: mail_add is reciepent's mail address

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a sample code to do it. This code assumes that you already have a collection of file paths to be converted in to `Attachments`.

```
        private static void SendEmail(IEnumerable<string> attachmentFilePaths)
        {
            string fromEmail = "abcd@gmail.com ";
            string mail_add = "recever@gmail.com";
            string subject = "hello";
            string body = "How are you?";

            try
            {
                using (MailMessage mailMessage = new MailMessage(fromEmail, mail_add, subject, body))
                {
                    foreach (var attachmentFilePath in attachmentFilePaths)
                    {
                        if (File.Exists(attachmentFilePath))
                        {
                            Attachment attachement = new Attachment(attachmentFilePath);
                            mailMessage.Attachments.Add(attachement);
                        }
                    }

                    MailAddress copy = new MailAddress(fromEmail);
                    mailMessage.CC.Add(copy);
                    using (SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient())
                    {
                        smtpClient.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
                        smtpClient.Port = 587;
                        smtpClient.EnableSsl = false;
                        smtpClient.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
                        smtpClient.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(fromEmail, "mis123");
                        smtpClient.Send(mailMessage);
                    }
                }
            }catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply execute `mailMessage.Attachments.Add` multiple times:

```
mailMessage.Attachments.Add(new System.Net.Mail.Attachment("path_with_xl_file"));
mailMessage.Attachments.Add(new System.Net.Mail.Attachment("path_with_xl_file_2"));
mailMessage.Attachments.Add(new System.Net.Mail.Attachment("path_with_xl_file_3"));
mailMessage.Attachments.Add(new System.Net.Mail.Attachment("path_with_xl_file_4"));
```

Of course, you can simplify this code by utilizing arrays, loops and other language instruments. It depends on how you store these 30 files in your program.
For example, if you store all pathes in a `string` array, you can do:

```
string[] pathes = /* ... */;
foreach (var path in pathes)
{
    mailMessage.Attachments.Add(new System.Net.Mail.Attachment(path));
}
```

Comment: are u suggest write above line more than 30 times??